# Re: Enterprise edition of our iPad app not downloading

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode6, ad-hoc-distribution, enterprise-distribution

We have created an enterprise edition of our iPad app. and we were using it since last 15 days. but url suddenly stopped working. we are not able to install application now.

Error: "There is no application set to open the URL itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=index.php%3Fplist%3DMyApp".
Earlier it was working fine, i din't change anything to my side.

Please help me out guys.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that the app is hosted on a server that gives the .ipa the correct MIME type, which should be "application/octet-stream." Any changes in your hosting server?
I've been in a situation where a Microsoft IIS server was not set properly and was screwing me up.